# How can I install a more modern web browser on 10.7.5 Mac Pro

Tags: icloud, macos, google-chrome, youtube

I have a workhorse of a MacPro built in early 2008. I can not afford a new Mac at the time, and this does everything I need it to except get to important websites such as iCloud, Square, YouTube, and various banks because the browsers are out dated.

I have been told Lion is the most-up-to date macOS I can install.

1. Is there a newer browser that is still supported by the websites
   above that can be installed on this mac.
2. Is there an Newer OS that can be installed
    **Must be compatible with Adobe CS3 or CS4

Please include helpful links if you know of any.

Comment: Precisely which Mac Pro? The "Early 08" 3,1 can run El Capitan so can run modern browsers.  menu > About this Mac > System report should identify it accurately in the first few lines if it's not completely clear from the About this Mac main screen.

Comment: RoaringApps says CS4 is fine with El Cap - https://roaringapps.com/app/adobe-cs4